# How to transfer large amounts of site pages to other wiki?

Tags: sharepoint-online, library, move, sitepages, open-with-explorer

We have many site pages in the standard site page library and would like to transfer them to a new website. how can this work? The "copy to" option only provides the option to move the content within the site the data. However, we want to move the modern pages to a completely different website. This library cannot be opened in Explorer. However, "Open in Explorer" works for other libraries. Apparently, the Site Page Library is not supported. You can open another library in the Explorer, then switch to the site page library and theoretically cut and paste the data there... but it does NOT work! How can we move our masses of Site Pages?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully copied modern pages using either the **Copy File** action in a Power Automate Flow, and also using the [PnP-PowerShell cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/copy-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps) **Copy-PnPFile**.

Both of these techniques successfully copy the Modern page and all of its webparts.  The one place that it falls short is that it does not copy any images which may be referenced by image webparts on the page, and doesn't change any hyperlinks that may be still pointing to pages on the source site.  If the permissions on the destination site are identical to those on source site, you probably won't notice any issues, as the copied page still has image webparts whose `src` elements are still pointing to the original site assets library on the source site.

If you need to copy the pages, as well as the referenced images, and "fixup" the new page to reference the new image locations, you may want to use a paid-for third party migration tool such as ShareGate, which can fix link and image references as it copies.

Comment: You can also use the Webpart "File Viewer" to connect modern pages with documents. Here you have the same problems as with the images?